# Get data from other component in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jsx

I have a constant that receives a json with a fetch like this:

`const [user, setUser] = useState([]);`

`async function users()  { const result = await fetch (`My API `,{
})

```
const data = await result.json();          
setUser(data);`
```

and i wanted to show her data in another component, for example just the name or just the id.

I want to put only the name on this little blue block : [this is the other component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QofmN.jpg)

[more of the second component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUOuu.jpg)

Comment: You can pass it through props. Can you show more code?

Comment: What do you wanna see

Comment: https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/sharing-state-between-components

Comment: thank you i read and learned how to do <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first component is the one where you obtain the data and the second the one you display it since your an receiving the user data by props

```
function FirstComponent(){
const [user, setUser] = useState([]);

 return (
   <SecondComponent user={user} />
 )
}

function SecondComponent({user}){
 console.log(user)

 return (
   //Here the code of the image you show
 )
}
```